# Highlight horizontal range on a Google Area Graph

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to implement an Area Chart using Google's chart api.

I've got this working using the basic code that they give, with one line charted as seen on the page linked below.

Is there a way to change this chart so that I can specify a different color to highlight a specific range.  For example, specify that from points 10 to 25 (along the X axis), the color is red instead of blue?

This is just Google's basic LineGraph example, though updated to AreaGraph instead...

I appreciate any help that is offered. :)

https://jsfiddle.net/brzdb4re/

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

    data.addRows([
        [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
        [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
        [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
        [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
        [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
        [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
        [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
        [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
        [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
        [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
        [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
        [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
    ]);

    var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Popularity'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```